# Matching OR expression using Grappa (Java PEG Parser)

Tags: java, peg, parboiled

I'm new to PEG parsing and trying to write a simple parser to parse out an expression like: "term1 OR term2 anotherterm" ideally into an AST that would look something like:

```
          OR
-----------|---------
|                    |
"term1"            "term2 anotherterm"
```

I'm currently using Grappa (https://github.com/fge/grappa) but it's not matching even the more basic expression "term1 OR term2". This is what I have:

```
package grappa;

import com.github.fge.grappa.annotations.Label;
import com.github.fge.grappa.parsers.BaseParser;
import com.github.fge.grappa.rules.Rule;

public class ExprParser extends BaseParser<Object> {

  @Label("expr")
  Rule expr() {
    return sequence(terms(), wsp(), string("OR"), wsp(), terms(), push(match()));
  }

  @Label("terms")
  Rule terms() {
    return sequence(whiteSpaces(),
        join(term()).using(wsp()).min(0),
        whiteSpaces());
  }

  @Label("term")
  Rule term() {
    return sequence(oneOrMore(character()), push(match()));
  }

  Rule character() {
    return anyOf(
        "0123456789" +
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
        "-_");
  }

  @Label("whiteSpaces")
  Rule whiteSpaces() {
    return join(zeroOrMore(wsp())).using(sequence(optional(cr()), lf())).min(0);
  }

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

(author of grappa here...)

OK, so, what you seem to want is in fact a parse tree.

Very recently there has been an extension to grappa (2.0.x+) developed which can answer your needs: https://github.com/ChrisBrenton/grappa-parsetree.

Grappa, by default, only "blindly" matches text and has a stack at its disposal, so you could have, for instance:

```
public Rule oneOrOneOrEtc()
{
    return join(one(), push(match())).using(or()).min(1));
}
```

But then all of your matches would have been on the stack... Not very practical, but still usable in some situations (see, for instance, [sonar-sslr-grappa](https://github.com/litesolutions/sonar-sslr-grappa)).

In your case you want this package. You can do this with it:

```
// define your root node
public final class Root
    extends ParseNode
{
    public Root(final String match, final List<ParseNode> children)
    {
        super(match, children);
    }
}

// define your parse node
public final class Alternative
    extends ParseNode
{
    public Alternative(final String match, final List<ParseNode> children)
    {
        super(match, children);
    }
}
```

That is the minimal implementation. And then your parser can look like this:

```
@GenerateNode(Alternative.class)
public Rule alternative() // or whatever
{
    return // whatever an alternative is
}

@GenerateNode(Root.class)
public Rule root
{
    return join(alternative())
        .using(or())
        .min(1);
}
```

What happens here is since the root node is matched before the alternative, if, say, you have a string:

```
a or b or c or d
```

then the root node will match the "whole sequence", and it will have four alternatives matching each a, b, c, and d.

Full credits here go to [Christopher Brenton](https://github.com/ChrisBrenton) for coming up with this idea in the first place!